# sql query for image to create table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been create register form using php and jquery without using database.

Now i want to create database and connect my php application.

So i created sql query below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crop` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`lname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`pass` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`age` int(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now i want to know, how to add code for image and date of birth, what is data type for these two input to store sql database.

Can anyone fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: For image you can use varchar(50) and for date use DATE as datatype..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DOB

```
`dob` date NOT NULL,
```

for image

```
`img` varchar(255) NOT NULL, // for only path and image name
```

or long like image rawdata

```
`img` BLOB NOT NULL,
`img` text NOT NULL,
```

[BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)

Comment: I need to upload photo for register form, i think data type for image "blob" right?

Comment: your welcome :) you can accept/upvote helpful answer

Comment: may i know sql query for select gender?

Comment: may i know sql query for select gender?

Comment: select gender from table where gender='male' or use type `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if some issue.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crop` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`lname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`pass` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`age` int(5) NOT NULL,
`thumg` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`dob` Date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```